# Insert into MySQL from MS SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, insert

I work on a SQL Server 2016. In this Server has a linkedserver connection to MySQL. Now I want to insert from a local mssql table to a MySQL table.

My code is:

```
INSERT OPENQUERY (
    MYSQL_BEWERTUNG
    ,'SELECT PERSONALNR, EINSATZSART, KUNDENNR FROM tb_bewertung'
)
SELECT b.PERSONALNR
    ,b.DATUMVON
    ,b.KUNDENNR
FROM ext_bewertungen b
```

After that execution, I get an message that 136 rows are effected.

If I look into the MySQL table, I can't find the new rows. But if I look from the MS SQL server with

```
SELECT PERSONALNR
    ,EINSATZSART
    ,KUNDENNR
FROM OPENQUERY(MYSQL_BEWERTUNG, 'SELECT PERSONALNR, EINSATZSART, KUNDENNR 
FROM tb_bewertung')
ORDER BY 1;
```

the new rows were shown.

Could someone explain me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you validate those changes ? (COMMIT)

Comment: no, I only execute this query like I show in my post. Should I commit? And what commit?

Comment: COMMIT may well be the issue (though a subsequent SELECT statement is working, that may be within the same transaction), but there's also a possibility that the specific database you are looking at on mysql is not the one that the linked server is populating. Have a look at the linked server definition.

Comment: I tried the other way, I change a field directly on mysql. I did not get the changes in my mssql server after a select. I have to check If I am on the right database... I give a feedback.

Comment: solved, the external webhoster build up a new serveraddress, my IT change the linkedserver to the new address. I did not checked all my emails after holidays... LOL, sorry and thanks for help

Comment: @SamEnbank You should answer your own question and mark it as accepted if you found a solution

Comment: done, I am able to solve it in two days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem, the t-sql is right, my IT change the webserver and change in my holidays my linkedserver also, thats why i did not see any changes... thanks @MandyShaw for the idea if I am on the wrong server =)